# Center a div with animation and vh units in css?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, viewport-units

So I've got a div, let's say `width: 7vh; height: 7vh; background: black;` and it's inside another div, `background: orange; height: 7vh; width: 100%;`. I've got an animation, which is supposed to uncenter it. Currently I am using `left: 50%` on the inner div, but obviously that's close to centering, but not really it. `margin: 0 auto;` or `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` don't animate. So what do I do? Is calculating the distance with JS my only solution?

**JsFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/8e7dk/

This example doesn't center it, it only comes close to doing so, by using `left: 50%;`

Comment: please include your code in the question and even better, make a fiddle out of it.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal demo with whatever code you've so far and explain what you want to do..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can center the square with `margin-left:-3.5vh;` at the beginning of the animation and animate it to 0 in your keyframe animation :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/8e7dk/2/)**

*CSS :*

```
#outer{
    background: orange;
    height: 7vh;
    width: 100%;
}
#logo{
    height: 7vh;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-3.5vh;
    width: 7vh;
    -webkit-animation: moveLeft 1s forwards ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: moveLeft 1s forwards ease-in-out;
    -ms-animation: moveLeft 1s forwards ease-in-out;
    -o-animation: moveLeft 1s forwards ease-in-out;
    animation: moveLeft 1s forwards ease-in-out;
    background: black;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveLeft {
    from {left: 50%;margin-left:-3.5vh;}
    to {left: 0;margin-left:0; -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-o-keyframes moveLeft {
    from {left: 50%;margin-left:-3.5vh;}
    to {left: 0;margin-left:0; -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes moveLeft {
    from {left: 50%;margin-left:-3.5vh;}
    to {left: 0;margin-left:0; -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@keyframes moveLeft {
    from {left: 50%;margin-left:-3.5vh;}
    to {left: 0;margin-left:0; -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think that it is possible to use left and margin-left together.